# Why does exporting the socket.io server as a constant using module.exports? make it undefined?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, node-modules

I am runnnig a socketserver in express but I am unable to export the io constant to a different file without it becoming undefined. I, therefore, cannot use io.on( ), it gives a type error.  When i tried to console.log it, its undefined.  Please help

server.js:

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);
// const io = new Server(server, options)
io.on("connection", socket => { console.log('hello') });

...

module.exports = {httpServer, app, io};
```

router.js:

```
const  {io}  = require("../server.js");
// console.log(io)
```

Comment: The export statement is missing at the end of `server.js`: `module.exports = io;`

Comment: Hi Heiko TheiBen.. i actually have the module.exports in my code. I updated my question to reflect that. 

For some reason it just doesn't carry the information as I export it.. and I understand it might have something to do with the order the modules are loaded.

Comment: Is your `server.js` really one directory level higher than `router.js`?  Otherwise, you should say `const {io} = require("./server.js");`

Comment: I  tested your code. But in my case, `io` object was exported correctly, I can access its methods on another file.